# Can the two subscribers from diffrent ISPs has same ip address?

Tags: networking

Suppose there are 2 different company(i.e ISP) say,

- Reliance
- Airtel.

These provide broadband connection. One customer from Airtel has IP 55.69.82.111. Is it possible the customer from reliance has the same ip address 55.69.82.111?

If yes,how? Else no,why?
If no,
I also read that by the concept of subnet mask, ip address can be repeated within the group of computers then if the ISPs are follow that subnet concept then may be the ip address will redundant.

Comment: A highly unlikely possibility because ISPs are given ranges of addresses at their disposal and no other ISP should be given addresses within the same range as another. But, I guess, there is a tiny possibility for error... It would surprise me if they didn't have systems that ensure this didn't happen...

Answer (score 1):

NO! it never happens. Because the IP addresses are provided by DHCP. So errors cant be happen, 2 same ip's will not be given to the customers.
Infact Each ISP has their own Network range. 
example  Airtel has 55.69.x.x  network range But Reliance should have their own network range ex: 180.42.x.x

So Airtel could not assign a IP address from the Reliance Network range....
hope you understand

Comment: Unless they're sharing a proxy server; or, within the ISP's network, they use private network addresses, for example, in the 10.0.0.0/8 range

Comment: Who determines the ranges? Much like root certificate authorities, is there a central body that assigns ranges?

Comment: @BigChris: Yes, IANA assigns ranges to [RIRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry), which then assign to ISPs.

Comment: In India all private ISPs obtain network ranges from IRINN. Govt. of India

Comment: I disagree with your postulate that 'it never happens'. Though very unlikely, a faulty DHCP configuration at the ISP could possibly result in the same IP address being assinged to two different hosts.

Comment: its very rare. it doesnt happens every time

Comment: So as per you answer,when ipv6 is not introduced at that time ipv4 has range which is 2^32.So,in all over the world,only 2^32(i.e 4294967296) people can get online at same time?what is the provision for 4294967297 user?As you say,no provision for assign same ip address then,How that ip was given to that 4294967297 user at the time of ipv4?

Comment: as the number of peoples using the internet grows. Technologies also got improved and managing the space. ISP's use Proxy Servers.

Comment: means you say that's why the ipv6 introduced,ok i agree.But my question is that at the time of ipv4 How the ip was given to that 4294967297 user?which is out of the range of the ipv4.That 4294967297 user will not get any ip?

Comment: During that days, there are not so many users in the world who uses the internet. The peoples who made IP Addresses allocated a bunch of address 127.0.0.0 to 127.255.255.255 for only loopback testing... That time they never realized that the Internet will grow as now today.
They may used only one IP for loopback testing (127.0.0.1).
think how many addresses could be given to peoples..

Comment: @Anbu:can you explain 'loopback testing' term.I can't understand.rest is good

Comment: Google is our Friend!!!

Comment: Is there any subnet mask concept is there which make the ip redundant?

Comment: yes! and a lot. Its all complicated for beginners

Comment: Because of this concept,I am confused this above  ip discussion.Because i heard about that.SO IF this concept is occur in ip then how we say that ip can not redundant then,HOW IS IT POSSIBLE IP CAN BE REDUNDANT BY CONCEPT OF SUBNET?SO,may be ISPs will implement this subnet concept and make the ip redundant.

Answer (score 0):

> One customer from Airtel has IP 55.69.82.111. 
>   Is it possible the customer from reliance has the same ip address 55.69.82.111?

No, this should never happen.

The [Internet Assigned Numbers Authority](http://www.internetassignednumbersauthority.org/) (IANA) delegates ranges of numbers. It hands out these ranges (numbers) only once, so every receiver has an unique range.

Suppose it hands out 55.68.0.0. though 55.69.255.255 to Airtel. Then airtel is can subdivide and distribute that subrange as it wishes. Another ISP will never get the same range.

> I also read that by the concept of subnet mask, ip address can be repeated within
>   the group of computers then if the ISPs are follow that subnet concept then may be
>   the ip address will redundant.

I suspect you mean the hostpart of the IP address may be repeated.

E.g. if I have three networks: 20.0.0.0/8, 21.0.0.0/8 and 22.0.0.0/8 then there is no problem to have three hosts with IP numbers 20.0.0.42, 21.0.0.42 and 22.0.0.42. For all three the host part is 0.0.42, but the network part if different.

The only exception to this is when you are absolutely sure that your network will never connect to the Internet. That way you have full control of your own **local** network. (And thus you take over the role to make sure that IPs are unique in your local net).

If you ever need to mix a local controller part and the Internet then use RFC1918 addresses (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0./24. Those are specifically declared to be local IPs. These should never be routed to the Internet and thus you also have no conflict with other people using those IPs.